# groupby trouble converting to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, df, with the following columns:

```
id                  int64
quarter    datetime64[ns]
decile              int64
dtype: object
```

When I run a groupby,

```
df.groupby(['id', 'quarter'])
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I think the right question is: What is the `dtypes` output not telling me so that I can in fact use my `int` and `datetime` to an index?

```
versions:
pandas: 0.25.1
python: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Additional observation regarding the error: The error goes away if I avoid renaming the columns beforehand.  The success of the renaming is confirmed when I run the `dtypes` method.

Finally, here is another example of the same error arising after a `groupby` and renaming (the renaming is silly in this example, but required when I include `date` in my aggregation; I only show the minimum code required to generate the error)

```
# resample to quarterly
quart = df.groupby(
[pd.Grouper(key='id'),
 pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='Q')]).agg({'call_qty':'sum'})

quart.columns = [['call_qty']]  # << toggle this renaming code to trigger the error

F = quart['call_qty'].isna()
```

Generates the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Thank you to anyone that might know something about this.

Comment: Do you get that error from **just** `df.groupby(['id', 'quarter'])` or does the line that throws the error have some other stuff chained on after the groupby? I don't see anything inherently wrong with that groupby.

Comment: The error is generated as I have it; only the `groupby`.  For what it's worth, the error also happens with just grouping by `id`.

Comment: Please provide an example of DataFrame, for which this error occurs (possibly minimal in size), and what version of *Python* and *Pandas* you use.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error, but with no success.

The source DataFrame I created as:

```
   id    quarter  decile
0   1 2019-01-01       5
1   1 2019-01-01       6
2   2 2019-04-01       1
3   2 2019-04-01       2
4   2 2019-07-01       3
5   2 2019-07-01       4
```

(with *dtype*s just as you described).

I tried grouping **alone**, just as you claim in your comment:

```
gr = df.groupby(['id', 'quarter'])
```

and **no error** occurred.

To test the result, I computed the mean of each group:

```
gr.mean()
```

getting:

```
               decile
id quarter           
1  2019-01-01     5.5
2  2019-04-01     1.5
   2019-07-01     3.5
```

As another test, I printed the content of each group:

```
for key, grp in gr:
    print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{grp}')
```

getting:

```
Group: (1, Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'))
   id    quarter  decile
0   1 2019-01-01       5
1   1 2019-01-01       6

Group: (2, Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00'))
   id    quarter  decile
2   2 2019-04-01       1
3   2 2019-04-01       2

Group: (2, Timestamp('2019-07-01 00:00:00'))
   id    quarter  decile
4   2 2019-07-01       3
5   2 2019-07-01       4
```

So, as you can see, with "normal" (presented above) source data no error occurs.

Maybe you have some older version of either *Python* or *Pandas*?
Upgrade to the current version and repeat your test.